# Strange error Undefined index "Item"

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I'm getting this error. Is strange because the index exists.

This is the array:

```
array(8) {
 ["OrderID"]=>
   string(6) "201646"
 ["FolioNo"]=>
   string(12) "540840840840"
 ["InvoiceID"]=>
   string(3) "277"
 ["CreatedOn"]=>
   object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression)#1252 (1) {
     ["value":protected]=>
        string(9) "GETDATE()"
     }
 ["CreatedBy"]=>
   string(1) "4"
 ["Item"]=>
   string(8) "Lien New"
 ["ItemDescriptions"]=>
   string(8) "Lien New"
 ["ItemPrice"]=>
   string(6) "150.00"
}
```

Sharing a screenshot with a print_r of $data
[image]

The error is thrown when I try to search for that record on database using next line in Laravel.

```
$itemExist = InvoiceItem::where('OrderID', $data['OrderID'])->where('Item', $data['Item'])->pluck('ItemID');
```

Var $data is created in different steps, when the system needs to create a kind of item ...

```
private function createRushInvoiceItem($order){
    if($order->IsRUSHOrder == 1){
        $data = $this->getExpensesData($order);
        $data = array_merge($data, [
            'Item' => "Lien RUSH",
            'ItemDescriptions' => "Lien RUSH",
            'ItemPrice' => $this->getClientPrice($order, 3)
        ]);

        $this->createInvoiceItem($data);
    }
}
```

first, I'm setting common values:

```
public function getExpensesData($order) {
    $data = [
        "OrderID" => $order->OrderID,
        "FolioNo" => $order->Property->FolioNo,
        'InvoiceID' => $this->getInvoiceID($order->OrderID),
    ];

    # Getting timeStamps for this record on create
    $data = $this->setTimeStamps($data, 'C');
    return $data;
}

public function setTimeStamps($data, $section) {
    if($section == 'C') {
         $data = array_merge($data, [
            'CreatedOn' => DB::raw('GETDATE()'),
            'CreatedBy' => Auth::user()->UserID
        ]);
    } else {
        $data = array_merge($data, [
            'UpdatedOn' => DB::raw('GETDATE()'),
            'UpdatedBy' => Auth::user()->UserID
        ]);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Finally I'm creating the item, here is when the error appears

```
public function createInvoiceItem($data) {
    $itemExist = InvoiceItem::where('OrderID', $data['OrderID'])->where('Item', $data['Item'])->pluck('ItemID');

    try {
        return !is_null($itemExist)? InvoiceItem::where('ItemID', $itemExist)->update($data) : InvoiceItem::create($data);
    }
    catch (Expection $exc) {
        return $exc->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as it is. Can you add the code where $data is defined?

Comment: sure man! I already did!

Comment: You are right, I have been hypnotised by `var_dump`.

Comment: hehehehe that's way I prefer print_r() most of the times when is not necessary more information. I try to get the result of that query and... this is an X file for me.. when I `print_r($itemExist);` **after** query, I can see the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Well guys, I had to change the way of the process to create the different items to fix it. More lines of code but is working.

Thanks anyway.